# Autofac WEBAPI inserting Controller dependencies through properties

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I have the following WebAPI Controller (I have removed most of the code for brevity)

```
public class ConnectionController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the connection manager.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The connection manager.
    /// </value>
    public IConnectionManagerService ConnectionManager
    {
        get;
        set;

    }
```

}

I am trying to insert the IConnectionManagerService through AutoFac and this is the code I have so far

```
// Create the container builder.
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register the Web API controllers.
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// Register other dependencies.
builder.Register(c => new ConnectionManagerService()).As<IConnectionManagerService>().InstancePerRequest();                      

// Build the container.
var container = builder.Build();

// Create the depenedency resolver.
var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

// Configure Web API with the dependency resolver.
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

Now inside the controller when I try to Use ConnectionManager I get null.  I thought Autofac will automatically include the dependency?  I dont want to include this dependency through a constructor parameter in the controller.

Comment: Is there any other concrete reason to not you constructor injection beside that you don't want to do that?

Comment: Not really, I just want to stick to the standard that comes out of the box as much as possible rather than making modifications to support DI.

Comment: It is considered best practice to use constructor injection. Don't be mislead to the code the Visual Studio generates by default. The default VS templates often don't communicate best practices.

Comment: To use constructor injection, do I need to make any chances to the Controller, I actually did try constructor injection, but it does not even instantiate the constructor, I am sure I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve properties injection in Autofac you should just use PropertiesAutowired extension method. In your autofac configuration after line:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

insert line:

```
builder.RegisterType<ConnectionController>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

Then if something is registerd in your container builder as IConnectionManagerService it will be assigned to ConnectionManager property.